# String operator += sometimes not working after string::resize()

Tags: c++, stl

Assuming:

```
std::string ToShow,NumStr;
```

The following displays "This is 19 ch00":

```
ToShow = "This is nineteen ch";
ToShow.resize(ToShow.length()+0);
NumStr = "00";
ToShow += NumStr;
mvaddstr(15,0,ToShow.c_str());
```

And the following displays "This is 19 ch  ":

```
ToShow = "This is nineteen ch";
ToShow.resize(ToShow.length()+1);
NumStr = "0";
ToShow += NumStr;
mvaddstr(16,0,ToShow.c_str());
```

In the second case, operator+= isn't adding the string "0" to the end of ToShow. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I would think the extra element from `resize` would be a `'\0'`. That would explain it if it's correct.

Comment: Count your characters and compare them to the size you pass to `mvaddstr`.  Also, your example is confusing.  You say - *"The following displays "This is 19 ch00":"*, which it obviously does not because your string is `"This is nineteen ch"`.  Note that `"19"` and `"nineteen"` are not the same thing.

Comment: Ed S: The text was just a filler; presumably "-------------------" would have been clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:

You don't specify the value to resize with, so after `ToShow.Resize(ToShow.length()+1)` your string looks like:

```
"This is nineteen ch\0"
```

And after `+= NumStr`:

```
"This is nineteen ch\00"
```

which, after calling c_str, gets trimmed to the first `\0` and looks like:

```
"This is nineteen ch"
```

(C strings are null-terminated, std::strings aren't)

Try calling `.resize(someLength, ' ')` instead.